# Target Display Mode with PC

Tags: display, windows, imac, thunderbolt-display, target-display

I have a 21-inch late 2013 iMac that I want to use as a monitor for my Windows Laptop. I am trying to use target display mode. My Laptop has thunderbolt 3 and HDMI outputs. What adapter can I get to do this?

On amazon, an HDMI to thunderbolt2/mini display port seems to have thunderbolt 2 on the output side instead of input like I need.